# Kernel of a specific matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A \in \mathbb R^{n \times m}$ with full column rank. Let $\tilde{A} = PA$, where $P$ is a permutation matrix permuting the rows of $A$.

What can be said about the kernel of the extended matrix $$\begin{pmatrix} \tilde{A} & A \end{pmatrix}$$ then?

Is the kernel always contained in the image of $$\begin{pmatrix} I \\ - \tilde{P} \end{pmatrix}$$ for some permutation $\tilde{P}$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. If the kernel of $(\tilde{A},A)$ and the image of $\pmatrix{I\\ -\tilde{P}}$ have a nonzero intersection, we would have $(\tilde{A},A)\pmatrix{I\\ -\tilde{P}}x=(PA-A\tilde{P})x=0$ for some nonzero vector $x$. Therefore, to disprove your conjecture, it suffices to find some $A$ and $P$ such that $(\tilde{A},A)$ has a **nontrivial** kernel and $PA-A\tilde{P}$ has full column rank for every permutation matrix $\tilde{P}$. For instances, let
$$
A=\pmatrix{1&0\\ 0&2\\ 1&1},\ P=\pmatrix{0&1&0\\ 0&0&1\\ 1&0&0},\ \tilde{A}=PA=\pmatrix{0&2\\ 1&1\\ 1&0}.
$$
$(\tilde{A},A)$ is $3\times4$, so it has a nontrivial kernel. Now, for $\tilde{P}=I$ and $\tilde{P}=\pmatrix{0&1\\ 1&0}$, the results of $PA-A\tilde{P}$ are respectively $\pmatrix{-1&2\\ 1&-1\\ 0&-1}$ and $\pmatrix{0&1\\ -1&1\\ 0&-1}$. Both of them have full column rank.

Comment: The question if, if the kernel of $(\tilde{A}, A)$ is CONTAINED in the image of the given matrix, not EQUAL. Therefore, your answer is wrong.

Comment: @samsa44 Huh? If $\ker(\tilde{A},A)$ is nonzero but $\ker(\tilde{A},A)\cap S=0$ for some set $S$, there is no way that $\ker(\tilde{A},A)$ is a subset of $S$.

Comment: but your answer contains only an example, where the kernel of $(\tilde{A},A)$ is trivial, if I am not mistaken?

Comment: @samsa44 I think I have made it very clear in my answer that my $(\tilde{A},A)$ is $3\times4$ and hence it has a nontrivial kernel. You have four vectors in a three dimensional vector space. They must be linearly dependent, mustn't they?

Comment: Of course, I am very sorry for being too rash. Do you think that the claim in the question can be true if you consider e.g. $\tilde{A}, A \in \mathbb R^{4 \times 2}$ ?